# Why are my Copilot shortcuts not working? (show next / previous suggestion)

Tags: javascript, github, github-copilot

I'm having a problem with Copilot shortcuts on Mac.

I'm using a czech keyboard so the default shortcuts for Next / Previous suggestions (option+] / option+[) don't work (as the key combionation just makes a literal bracket.

Even though I bind it to different key combinations, the shortcuts don't work. What's wrong?

(The files below are my settings.json and keybinds.json)
[image: copilot bindings]

```json
{
  "security.workspace.trust.startupPrompt": "never",
  "security.workspace.trust.enabled": false,
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "files.associations": {
    ".py": "Python",
    "*.sql": "sql",
    "*.js": "javascript",
    "*.css": "css",
  },
  "editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": "on",
    "comments": "off",
    "strings": true
  },
  "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
  "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/usr/local/bin/python3.10",
  "workbench.preferredLightColorTheme": "Tomorrow Night Blue",
  "workbench.preferredDarkColorTheme": "Kimbie Dark",
  "zenMode.hideLineNumbers": false,
  "zenMode.centerLayout": false,
  "editor.cursorBlinking": "solid",
  "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
  "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
  "editor.fontSize": 16,
  "git.confirmSync": false,
  "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
  "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
  "gitlens.currentLine.enabled": false,
  "gitlens.hovers.currentLine.over": "line",
  "vsicons.dontShowNewVersionMessage": true,
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash",
  "[4GL]": {
    "files.encoding": "iso88592"
  },
  "[plaintext]": {
    "editor.suggest.showWords": true
  },
  "reactSnippets.settings.prettierEnabled": true,
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
  },
  "[sql]": {},
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Atom One Dark",
  "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
  "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
  "editor.linkedEditing": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "[javascriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[css]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[typescriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[svelte]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[python]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.python",
    "editor.formatOnType": true
  },
  "[jsonc]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.json-language-features"
  },
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "[java]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "redhat.java"
  },
  "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
  "github.copilot.enable": {
    "*": true
  },
  "rust-analyzer.checkOnSave.command": "clippy",
  "[rust]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "rust-lang.rust-analyzer",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  },
  "bracket-pair-colorizer-2.depreciation-notice": false,
  "[toml]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "tamasfe.even-better-toml"
  },
  "crates.localCargoIndexBranch": "origin/HEAD",
  "crates.useLocalCargoIndex": false,
  "git.openRepositoryInParentFolders": "always",
  "launch": {
    "configurations": [],
    "compounds": []
  },
  "code-runner.customCommand": "cargo run",
  "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
  "code-runner.saveAllFilesBeforeRun": true,
  "terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
    "FIG_NEW_SESSION": "1"
  },
  "workbench.editorAssociations": {
    "*.md": "vscode.markdown.preview.editor"
  },
  "rust-analyzer.lens.implementations.enable": false,
  "postcssSorting.config": {
    "properties-order": "alphabetical",
  },
  "workbench.sideBar.location": "right",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "svelte.enable-ts-plugin": true,
}
```

```json
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaultsauto[]
[
  {
    "key": "cmd+r",
    "command": "editor.action.changeAll",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+enter",
    "command": "-editor.action.insertLineAfter",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+l cmd+o",
    "command": "-extension.liveServer.goOnline",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+[IntlBackslash]",
    "command": "-editor.action.inPlaceReplace.up",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
  },
  {
    "key": "shift+enter",
    "command": "java.debug.runJavaFile"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+[BracketLeft]",
    "command": "editor.action.commentLine",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
  },
  {
    "key": "shift+cmd+[BracketLeft]",
    "command": "-editor.action.commentLine",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+i",
    "command": "-interactiveEditor.start",
    "when": "interactiveEditorHasProvider && !editorReadonly"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+i",
    "command": "-editor.action.triggerSuggest",
    "when": "editorHasCompletionItemProvider && textInputFocus && !editorReadonly && !suggestWidgetVisible"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+i",
    "command": "-focusSuggestion",
    "when": "suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus && !suggestWidgetHasFocusedSuggestion"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+i",
    "command": "-markdown.extension.editing.toggleItalic",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && editorLangId =~ /^markdown$|^rmd$|^quarto$/"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+i",
    "command": "-toggleSuggestionDetails",
    "when": "suggestWidgetHasFocusedSuggestion && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+i",
    "command": "editor.action.quickFix",
    "when": "editorHasCodeActionsProvider && editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+[Period]",
    "command": "-editor.action.quickFix",
    "when": "editorHasCodeActionsProvider && editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+enter",
    "command": "-notebook.cell.insertCodeCellBelow",
    "when": "notebookCellListFocused && !inputFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+enter",
    "command": "-search.action.openInEditor",
    "when": "hasSearchResult && searchViewletFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+f5",
    "command": "-workbench.action.debug.run",
    "when": "debuggersAvailable && debugState != 'initializing'"
  },
  {
    "key": "f5",
    "command": "-workbench.action.debug.start",
    "when": "debuggersAvailable && debugState == 'inactive'"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+enter",
    "command": "code-runner.runCustomCommand"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+alt+k",
    "command": "-code-runner.runCustomCommand"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+[IntlBackslash]",
    "command": "workbench.action.togglePanel"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+j",
    "command": "-workbench.action.togglePanel"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+o cmd+p",
    "command": "markdown.showPreviewToSide",
    "when": "!notebookEditorFocused && editorLangId == 'markdown'"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+k v",
    "command": "-markdown.showPreviewToSide",
    "when": "!notebookEditorFocused && editorLangId == 'markdown'"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+k cmd+c",
    "command": "-editor.action.addCommentLine",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+k cmd+c",
    "command": "-notebook.cell.collapseCellInput",
    "when": "notebookCellListFocused && !inputFocus && !notebookCellInputIsCollapsed"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+k cmd+c",
    "command": "-notebook.cell.expandCellInput",
    "when": "notebookCellInputIsCollapsed && notebookCellListFocused"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+k cmd+c",
    "command": "github.copilot.toggleCopilot"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+cmd+down",
    "command": "workbench.action.nextSideBarView"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+cmd+up",
    "command": "workbench.action.previousSideBarView"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+cmd+up",
    "command": "-workbench.action.terminal.focusPreviousPane",
    "when": "terminalFocus && terminalHasBeenCreated || terminalFocus && terminalProcessSupported"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+cmd+up",
    "command": "-editor.action.insertCursorAbove",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+cmd+down",
    "command": "-editor.action.insertCursorBelow",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+cmd+down",
    "command": "-workbench.action.terminal.focusNextPane",
    "when": "terminalFocus && terminalHasBeenCreated || terminalFocus && terminalProcessSupported"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+s",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": {
      "sequence": [
        "postcssSorting.execute",
        "workbench.action.files.save"
      ]
    },
    "when": "editorLangId == css"
  },
  {
    "key": "shift+cmd+[Period]",
    "command": "-breadcrumbs.focus",
    "when": "breadcrumbsPossible && breadcrumbsVisible"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+[BracketRight]",
    "command": "github.copilot.nextPanelSolution"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+[BracketLeft]",
    "command": "github.copilot.previousPanelSolution"
  },
  // {
  //   "key": "ctrl+[BracketRight]",
  //   "command": "editor.action.inlineSuggest.showNext",
  //   "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible"
  // },
  // {
  //   "key": "ctrl+[BracketLeft]",
  //   "command": "editor.action.inlineSuggest.showPrevious",
  //   "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible"
  // }
]
```